# Python dict from lists with key and valuelist

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have three lists of each x elements:

```
stat = ["A","B","C"]
X = [1,2,3]
Y = [10,15,20]
```

No I'd like to create dict out of that lists where
'stat' should be the key and X and Y are valuepairs stored
in a list of each two elements. The result
could look like:

```
my_dict = {
    "A" : [1,10],
    "B" : [2,15],
    "C" : [3,20]
}
```

or could even be a nested dict so that I can index it with my_dict["A"]["X"].

or is there any other way to get a "named array" in python?

As I have a second question which is very related to the first one I just add it here instead of opening a new one:

I am acutally very used to R's arrays. Thus my question.: Is there anything like a named array in python? E.g. I have two lists which represent
my column and rownames:

```
columns = ["A","B","C"], rows = ["row_a","row_b","row_c"]
```

Now I'd like to create an array from these two lists:

```
my_array = columns x rows
```

which I want to index with the names like:

```
my_array["A","row_b"]
```

and assign values to the "cells" (populate the array) in a loop.

Is it possible to do such things in python in an easy way? Probably this is done
also best with a dictionary to use indexing with strings..

Comment: If you come from R and want such functionality, you should look into numpy and scipy.

Comment: @Björn Pollex You're right...After reading some words about numpy, structured / record arrays seems to be a very good alternative for my purposes. Anyway I still need to understand them better. Any good book on numpy to recommend?

Comment: Sorry, I got it all from the documentation. It is not perfect, but together with stackoverflow, you should be able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> stat = ["A","B","C"]
>>> X = [1,2,3]
>>> Y = [10,15,20]
>>> dict(zip(stat, map(list, zip(X, Y))))
{'A': [1, 10], 'C': [3, 20], 'B': [2, 15]}
```

Comment: I like that way of using zip anyway this doesn't yet support to index it with two strings eg. my_dict['A']['X'].

Comment: That's work for me as well. This assists to me combine a dict object's list items with mapping.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> stat = ["A","B","C"]
>>> X = [1,2,3]
>>> Y = [10,15,20]
>>> {s:[x,y] for s,x,y in zip(stat, X, Y)}
{'A': [1, 10], 'C': [3, 20], 'B': [2, 15]}
```

To able to  use `my_dict["A"]["X"]` it's slightly different.

```
>>> {s:{'X':x, 'Y':y} for s,x,y in zip(stat, X, Y)}
{'A': {'Y': 10, 'X': 1}, 'C': {'Y': 20, 'X': 3}, 'B': {'Y': 15, 'X': 2}}
```

Python3 syntax is superior for the first way:

```
>>> stat = ["A","B","C"]
>>> X = [1,2,3]
>>> Y = [10,15,20]
>>> {k:v for k,*v in zip(stat, X, Y)}
{'A': [1, 10], 'C': [3, 20], 'B': [2, 15]}
```

Comment: This is a Python 3 feature, isn't it?

Comment: @BjörnPollex, dict comprehensions are in Python2.7+. But Python3 does add a nice way to unpack the zip

Answer (score 3):

Generator-expressions rule:

```
dict((key, [v1,v2]) for key, v1, v2 in zip(stat, X, Y))
```